# Как правильно написать: Правила эксплуатации детской игровой площадкой или площадки?

Tags: падежи

Правила эксплуатации детской игровой площадкой
или Правила эксплуатации детской игровой площадки?

Answer (score 2):

Эксплуатировать - *переходный* глагол: "эксплуатировать что?" - "площадк**у**".
Соответствующее отглагольное существительное: "эксплуатация чего?" - "площадк**и**" (винительный падеж при глаголе переходит в родительный при существительном, обозначающем действие этого глагола); правила эксплуатации чего? - площадк**и**.

Для сравнения - *непереходный* глагол: заведовать чем? - площадк**ой**; заведование чем? - площадк**ой** (в обеих формах - творительный падеж).